# How To Write This In CPS?

Tags: f#, continuation-passing

I'm trying to master continuation passing style (CPS) and am therefore reworking an example shown to me by Gary Short quite a while ago.  I don't have his sample source code so I'm trying to rework his example from memory. Consider the following code:

```
let checkedDiv m n =
    match n with
    | 0.0 -> None
    | _ -> Some(m/n)

let reciprocal r = checkedDiv 1.0 r

let resistance c1 c2 c3 =
     (fun c1 -> if (reciprocal c1).IsSome then 
        (fun c2 -> if (reciprocal c2).IsSome then
            (fun c3 -> if (reciprocal c3).IsSome then 
                Some((reciprocal c1).Value + (reciprocal c2).Value + (reciprocal c3).Value))));;
```

What I can't quite figure out is how to structure the resistance function.  I came up with this earlier:

```
let resistance r1 r2 r3 =
        if (reciprocal r1).IsSome then
            if (reciprocal r2).IsSome then
                if (reciprocal r3).IsSome then
                    Some((reciprocal r1).Value + (reciprocal r2).Value + (reciprocal r3).Value)
                else
                    None
            else
                None
        else
            None
```

but, of course, that's not using CPS--not to mention the fact that it seems really hacky and there's quite a bit of repeated code which also seems like a code smell.

Can someone show me how to rewrite the resistance function in a CPS way?

Comment: Can you use computation expressions? Or is that not CPS-compliant?

Comment: @Shlomo--that's not a bad suggestion but it's sort of putting the cart before the horse.  I'm trying to master CPS because CPS is part of the structure of computation expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

straightforward way:

```
let resistance_cps c1 c2 c3 = 
    let reciprocal_cps r k = k (checkedDiv 1.0 r)
    reciprocal_cps c1 <| 
        function
        | Some rc1 -> 
            reciprocal_cps c2 <| 
                function
                | Some rc2 -> 
                    reciprocal_cps c3 <|
                        function 
                        | Some rc3 -> Some (rc1 + rc2 + rc3)
                        | _ -> None
                | _ -> None
        | _ -> None
```

or a bit shorter with Option.bind

```
let resistance_cps2 c1 c2 c3 = 
    let reciprocal_cps r k = k (checkedDiv 1.0 r)
    reciprocal_cps c1 <|
        Option.bind(fun rc1 -> 
            reciprocal_cps c2 <| 
                Option.bind(fun rc2 ->
                    reciprocal_cps c3 <| 
                        Option.bind(fun rc3 -> Some (rc1 + rc2 + rc3))
                )
        )
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a known task from "Programming F#" book by Chris Smith; the CPS-style solution code is given on page 244 there:

```
let let_with_check result restOfComputation =
    match result with
    | DivByZero -> DivByZero
    | Success(x) -> restOfComputation x

let totalResistance r1 r2 r3 =
    let_with_check (divide 1.0 r1) (fun x ->
    let_with_check (divide 1.0 r2) (fun y ->
    let_with_check (divide 1.0 r3) (fun z ->
    divide 1.0 (x + y + z) ) ) )
```

Comment: Thanks for the reference; I've got Chris Smith's book so I'll read that portion of it.

Answer (score 2):

Using the Maybe monad defined [here](http://blog.matthewdoig.com/?p=98)

```
let resistance r1 r2 r3 =
  maybe {
    let! r1 = reciprocal r1
    let! r2 = reciprocal r2
    let! r3 = reciprocal r3
    return r1 + r2 + r3
  }
```

Comment: That's not a bad suggestion but I'm trying to work up to understanding monads and understanding CPS is part of understanding monads.

Comment: Then maybe a useful exercise would be desugaring this by looking at the definition of `Bind`.